# android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

I'm trying to open the `screenshots` photos folder.

```
        private void Try3()
        {
            File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Pictures/Screenshots");
            Log.d("File path ", dir.getPath());
            String dirPath=dir.getAbsolutePath();
            if(dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(dir));

                Log.d("b4performSpecificCrop_startActivityForResult::", Integer.toString(3));
                startActivityForResult(intent, 3);
                Log.d("afterperformSpecificCrop_startActivityForResult::", Integer.toString(3));
            }
```

I have this permission in the Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and get this from logCat:

```
10-05 22:17:26.790: E/AndroidRuntime(28347): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-05 22:17:26.790: E/AndroidRuntime(28347): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT dat=file:///storage/sdcard0/Pictures/Screenshots }
10-05 22:17:26.790: E/AndroidRuntime(28347):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1580)
10-05 22:17:26.790: E/AndroidRuntime(28347):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1431)
10-05 22:17:26.790: E/AndroidRuntime(28347):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3446)
10-05 22:17:26.790: E/AndroidRuntime(28347):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3407)
10-05 22:17:26.790: E/AndroidRuntime(28347):    at de.vogella.android.todos.TodoDetailActivity$1.Try3(TodoDetailActivity.java:149)
10-05 22:17:26.790: E/AndroidRuntime(28347):    at de.vogella.android.todos.TodoDetailActivity$1.onClick(TodoDetailActivity.java:132)
10-05 22:17:26.790: E/AndroidRuntime(28347):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4223)
10-05 22:17:26.790: E/AndroidRuntime(28347):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17275)
10-05 22:17:26.790: E/AndroidRuntime(28347):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
10-05 22:17:26.790: E/AndroidRuntime(28347):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-05 22:17:26.790: E/AndroidRuntime(28347):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-05 22:17:26.790: E/AndroidRuntime(28347):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
10-05 22:17:26.790: E/AndroidRuntime(28347):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-05 22:17:26.790: E/AndroidRuntime(28347):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-05 22:17:26.790: E/AndroidRuntime(28347):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
10-05 22:17:26.790: E/AndroidRuntime(28347):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
10-05 22:17:26.790: E/AndroidRuntime(28347):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-05 22:17:26.815: E/android.os.Debug(2282): !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
10-05 22:17:29.950: E/Watchdog(2282): !@Sync 36
10-05 22:17:31.460: E/WifiP2pStateTracker(2282): getNetworkInfo : NetworkInfo: type: WIFI_P2P[], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true
10-05 22:17:32.890: E/Sensors(2282): Gyro old sensor_state 75, new sensor_state : 73 en : 0
10-05 22:17:32.895: E/Sensors(2282): Pressure old sensor_state 73, new sensor_state : 65 en : 0
10-05 22:17:38.545: E/MtpService(2826): In MTPAPP onReceive:android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
10-05 22:17:38.550: E/MtpService(2826): battPlugged Type : 2
```

Update:

`ACTION_VIEW` doesn't work

`ACTION_GET_CONTENT` doesn't work

`ACTION_PICK` works, but I prefer the default photos Gallery view

I have read about these in the documentation, but didn't fully understand the difference between them. Can someone clear this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `setData()` wipes out your `setType()` IIRC. When you actually need both (hint: not here), set them both together with `setDataAndType()`.

Second, `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` is for choosing by type, not location. Quoting [the documentation for `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_GET_CONTENT):

> Note that no URI is supplied in the intent, as there are no constraints on where the returned data originally comes from

Hence, you will need to remove your `setData()` call and just use `setType()`. However, that will not pick from that folder.

`ACTION_PICK` is where you specify a collection to pick from, rather than a type. However, there is no guarantee that there will be an app on the device that supports `ACTION_PICK` for a `file://` `Uri`.

I would recommend that you implement the UI in your application directly.